# Resetting Threaded Events - C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio-2008, events, thread-safety

Let's say that I have a switch statement in my thread function that evaluates for triggered events.  Each case is a different event.  Is it better to put the call to `ResetEvent` at the end of the case, or at the beginning?  It seems to me that it should go at the end, so that the event cannot be triggered again, until the thread has finished processing the previous event.  IF it is placed at the beginning, the event could be triggered again, while being processed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  think that is the way to go. Create a manual reset event (second parameter of `CreateEvent` API) so that event is not automatically reset after setting it.

Answer (score 1):

If you handle incoming traffic using a single Event object (implying you have no inbound queue), you will miss events.  Is this really what you want?

If you want to catch all events, a full-blown producer-consumer queue wouold be a better bet.  Reference implementation for Boost.Thread [here](http://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/threading/implementing-a-thread-safe-queue-using-condition-variables.html).

> One problem that comes up time and
>   again with multi-threaded code is how
>   to transfer data from one thread to
>   another. For example, one common way
>   to parallelize a serial algorithm is
>   to split it into independent chunks
>   and make a pipeline — each stage in
>   the pipeline can be run on a separate
>   thread, and each stage adds the data
>   to the input queue for the next stage
>   when it's done. For this to work
>   properly, the input queue needs to be
>   written so that data can safely be
>   added by one thread and removed by
>   another thread without corrupting the
>   data structure.